# Having unity game saved to SD card can't run on certain devices but after it's moved to phone memory it works.. why?

Tags: c#, unity, android, deployment

A game I made ends up not being able to run (it shows the loading screen but after that it gets stuck), happens on nexus 5, sony experia z3 and I found this happening because the game was downloaded into the sd card memory. After moving it to the phone the game runs. I'm not sure why this is happening. Please help?

Comment: Did you set write access from build settings so External(Sd card) ?